# How to import excel data to drupal with custom module?

Tags: excel, drupal, import, drupal-modules

I always import data via navicat and there's no problem at all. But, I want to build a custom module in drupal, so authorized uses could import data from theirs excel's files to a table.

There's one excel file that contain headers and data like this:

### Name   Class   Grade

Abe     2       A
Aaron   1       C
Celeste 2       B

I want to put that data to a table called "grade_stat". How should i do it in custom modules? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how did you create that table, but I can recomend you to use [Data module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data) to create a tables like this, the module provides views module integration and [Feed](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) integration that allow you to import directly to your table by CSV files.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @Ludwig. Is "Data Module" can insert data from excel to existing table on mydatabase? I already installed "Feed" module, but I have no ideas to get it done :(

Comment: If you already create a table without any other module, you can do it only by your own module, Feeds works  for all entities created by Drupal entity standards.